# Selenium FindBy attributes using Javascript and Wait in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium, pageobjects

I am using Selenium and I have the following extensions methods for executing javascript.

```
    private const int s_PageWaitSeconds = 30;

    public static IWebElement FindElementByJs(this IWebDriver driver, string jsCommand)
    {
        return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(jsCommand);
    }

    public static IWebElement FindElementByJsWithWait(this IWebDriver driver, string jsCommand, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            wait.Until(d => d.FindElementByJs(jsCommand));
        }
        return driver.FindElementByJs(jsCommand);
    }

    public static IWebElement FindElementByJsWithWait(this IWebDriver driver, string jsCommand)
    {
        return FindElementByJsWithWait(driver, jsCommand, s_PageWaitSeconds);
    }
```

In my HomePage class I have the following attribute.

```
public class HomePage : SurveyPage
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "radio2")]
    private IWebElement employerSelect; 

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    public override SurveyPage FillOutThisPage()
    {
        employerSelect.Click();
        employerSelect.Submit();
        m_driver.FindElement(By.)
        return new Level10Page(m_driver); 
    }
}
```

However, employerSelect is generated by Javascript, so is there a way to do something like this:

```
public class HomePage : SurveyPage
{
    const string getEmployerJsCommand= "return $(\"li:contains('Employer')\")[0];";

    [FindsBy(How = How.FindElementByJsWithWait, Using = "getEmployerJsCommand")]
    private IWebElement employerSelect; 

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
    }

    public override SurveyPage FillOutThisPage()
    {
        employerSelect.Click();
        employerSelect.Submit();
        m_driver.FindElement(By.)
        return new Level10Page(m_driver); 
    }
}
```

In essence, I want to replace the raw ExecuteJs call as part of the FindsBy attribute such as:

```
    const string getEmployerJsCommand = "return $(\"li:contains('Employer')\")[0];";
    IWebElement employerSelect = driver.FindElementByJsWithWait(getEmployerJsCommand);
```

into part of the FindsBy attribute like this:

```
    const string getEmployerJsCommand= "return $(\"li:contains('Employer')\")[0];";

    [FindsBy(How = How.FindElementByJsWithWait, Using = "getEmployerJsCommand")]
    private IWebElement employerSelect;
```

What could I extend to do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `FindsByAttribute` is `sealed` in Selenium.  As a result you cannot override it to add new behaviuor. And `How` is an `Enum` so there is no way to to add new values without overriding the entire attribute class.

So there is no way to do what you would like currently.

However, I don't think that having FindsBy be sealed was a deliberate design decision, but a result of the fact that .NET Selenium is a direct port of Java Selenium.  In Java all classes are "sealed" by default and have to be explicitly marked virtual to allow for overriding. C# is the opposite, and I think most classes were marked sealed during the Java-C# port as a result without consideration as to whether it should be allowed or not.

Up until the latest version of Selenium, the `By` class was also sealed, and this was just fixed, and I'm taking advantage of it to create my own By lookups. (using jQuery selectors).  I'm sure one could submit a pull request to do the same for `FindsBy`

Comment: you are wrong, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263483/how-to-write-my-own-customize-locator-for-selenium-webdriver-in-java